# Save PDF to iBooks issue with xCode7

Tags: pdf, ibooks

```
func downloadPDF() {
        // Running operations that takes a long time in a background thread is recommended
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), { () -> Void in
            // Get the PDF data from the URL
            let url = self.webview.request?.URL
            let pdfURL = url?.absoluteString
            let pdfData = NSData(contentsOfURL: NSURL(string: pdfURL!)!)!

            // Store the data locally as a PDF file in the Documents directory
            let documentsDirPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true).first as? String
            localPdfPath = documentsDirPath.stringByAppendingPathComponent(pdfURL!.lastPathComponent)
            pdfData.writeToFile(localPdfPath, atomically: true)

            // UI related stuff should be called in the main thread.
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
                self.openIniBooks()
                self.stopActivityIndicator()
            })
        })
    }
```

Save PDF file to iBooks was working fine until upgrade to xCode7.  Now getting an error:
*Downcast from String? to String only unwraps optionals...* for this line:

```
let documentsDirPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true).first as? String
```

Not sure how to fix that.  Tried:

```
let documentsDirPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0] as String
```

But got new error. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    let documentsDirPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true).first as String!
```

Comment: How do you implement self.openIniBooks() ? Thanks

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer!